# How can I set up private guard nodes for a tor hidden service?

Tags: server, routes, tor

I've heard of some kind of sniper attack within the TOR network, basically, it allows a hacker to become a guard node to a hidden service and thus discover its true IP address. I've read that you can set up private guard nodes as a means to counter this sniper attack, allowing the server machine to connect to nodes you control, though I can't seem to find an article describing how to do so.

Does anyone have a link to an article about this or otherwise knows how to set up private guard nodes for a tor hidden service?

Comment: https://github.com/mikeperry-tor/vanguards As outlined in the [technical readme](https://github.com/mikeperry-tor/vanguards/blob/master/README_TECHNICAL.md) one of its major defenses is to protect against guard discovery.

Answer (score 0):

In your `torrc` add yours and friends' nodes & bridges in: `EntryNodes, HSLayer2Nodes, HSLayer3Nodes`

[man torrc](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/tor/torrc.5.en.html)

```
# A list of identity fingerprints and country codes of nodes to use for the first hop in your normal circuits.
EntryNodes node,node,...
# A list of identity fingerprints, nicknames, country codes, and address patterns of nodes that are allowed to be used as the second hop in all client or service-side Onion Service circuits.
HSLayer2Nodes node,node,...
# A list of identity fingerprints, nicknames, country codes, and address patterns of nodes that are allowed to be used as the third hop in all client and service-side Onion Service circuits.
HSLayer3Nodes node,node,...
```

HSLayer[2&3]Nodes option is meant to be managed by Mike Perry's [vanguards](https://github.com/mikeperry-tor/vanguards) onion service addon. *The README's are recently updated.*

Nodes lists and vanguards, both can be used on the onion service server and also on the Tor client machine.

Comment: Better suited for [tor.stackexchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com)